# Given $ty'' + 3y' = - te^t$ and $W(y_1,y_2)(1) = 2$ ($y_1$ and $y_2$ are LI solutions) find $W(y_1,y_2)(2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

If y1 and y2 are two linearly independent solutions of $ty'' + 3y' = -te^t$ and if $W (y1, y2) (1) = 2$, find $W (y1, y2) (2)$.

What I have tried:

Bashing my head on the wall, I have absolutely no idea where to start. I thought it has something to do with Abel's theorem but the EDO is not homogeneous.

Comment: There's probably an easier way to do this, but if I didn't know what to do I'd just start by solving the equation. Try substituting $u = y',$ I think you'll find the equation much easier to deal with.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#Application_to_linear_differential_equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ty'' + 3y' = - te^t$$
$$y'' + \dfrac 3ty' = - e^t$$
You can use Abel's Identity:
$$y''+py'+qy=0$$
$$\implies W'+pW=0$$
So that we have :
$$ \implies W'+\dfrac 3tW=0$$
Solve the ODE to get the Wronskian $W$:
$$(\ln W)'=-\dfrac 3t$$
$$W(t)=Ct^{-3}$$
$$W(1)=2 \implies C=2$$
$$W(t)=2t^{-3}$$
Now you can deduce $W(2)$.

Comment: Thank you Aryadeva. Can you tell how you did the transition from $y'' + \frac{3}{t}y' = -e^t$ to $W' + \frac{3}{t}W = 0$?

Comment: It's Abel's theorem...  Check the wiki page...not that it dosent matter that the ODE is not homogeneous...I put the ODE in the canonical form.   @rumpelstiltskin

Comment: Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity  @rumpelstiltskin

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. Can you tell why we can use Abel's theorem even with the EDO being non homogeneous?

Comment: The wronskian has nothing to do with the inhomogeneous part..It only uses solutions to the homogeneous ODE. You're welcome @rumpelstiltskin